# after checkbox is checked can't show onclicklistener

Tags: android, android-volley

I have a problem with onclicklistener in checkbox.where checkbox does not work

so here my code:

```
checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        String position = sebab.isChecked();
                                        getKonsultasiutils getSebab = (com.example.ikhwan.ta.getKonsultasiutils) arrayList.get(position);

                                        Toast.makeText(MenuTransaksi.this, getSebab.getKd_sebab(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        getKd_sebab = getSebab.getKd_sebab();


                                    }
                                }
```

this warning is incompatble type in String position.

i want show data string when button checked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do something when a checkbox change state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332111/how-to-do-something-when-a-checkbox-change-state)

Comment: `sebab.isChecked()` is likely to be a `boolean`. You can't assign it to a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

`CompoundButton.isChecked()` returns a `boolean`, not a `String`, so you cannot write `String s = checkBox.isChecked()`. If you want to assign it to a `String`, you could instead write `String s = String.valueOf(checkBox.isChecked())`.

Additionally, in the code you posted, you named your `String` `position`, and then pass the value to `arrayList.get()`. In this context, position should be an `int`, not a `String` or a `boolean`.